# Screenshot code gives unexpected error on call to GetDIBits

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm using some C code to take a screenshot of a window, translated directly from a PowerBuilder sample that works perfectly. Here's the part up to where there's a problem:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall WindowScreenShot(const wchar_t* fileName, unsigned long x, unsigned long y,
    unsigned long width, unsigned long height)
{
    HWND ll_hWnd;
    HDC ll_hdc, ll_hdcMem;
    HBITMAP ll_hBitmap;
    HANDLE hDib = NULL, hFile = NULL;
    char* lpBitmap = NULL;
    BOOL lb_result, lb_ok = FALSE;
    BITMAPINFO lstr_Info;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER lstr_Header;
    int li_pixels;
    DWORD dwBmpSize, dwBytesWritten;

    // get handle to windows background
    ll_hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();

    // Get the device context of window and allocate memory
    ll_hdc = GetDC(ll_hWnd);
    ll_hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(ll_hdc);
    ll_hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(ll_hdc, width, height);

    if (ll_hBitmap != 0)
    {
        // Select an object into the specified device context
        SelectObject(ll_hdcMem, ll_hBitmap);
        // Copy the bitmap from the source to the destination
        lb_result = BitBlt(ll_hdcMem, 0, 0, width, height, ll_hdc, x, y, SRCCOPY);
        lstr_Info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        // Get the bitmapinfo (THIS LINE IS FAILING CURRENTLY)
        if (GetDIBits(ll_hdcMem, ll_hBitmap, 0, height, NULL, &lstr_Info, DIB_RGB_COLORS) > 0)
        { ...
```

That last call to `GetDIBits` always fails with the only documented error that it can give, `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Since this code is basically absolutely identical to the PowerBuilder code, in terms of the structures used and Windows APIs called, I just have no idea how to resolve it. I've also read the API docs carefully and it all looks like it should work.

Any bright ideas? Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the example over at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image fills in more fields of the bitmap header before passing it to GetDIBits.

Comment: `lstr_Info` is an automatic variable and contains garbage. You must properly initialize it.

Comment: Thank you Paul! Shows what happens when you only program in C quite occasionally, I forget things like having to initialize automatic variables that used to be second nature to me when I did it all the time! That resolved the problem. 
The Microsoft example from AKX didn't work for me, it somehow messed up the original window it was taking a screenshot of, before taking that screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Ogilvie's answer resolved it - I was using uninitialized structures because they were automatic variables. As soon as I fixed that the code worked.

Comment: *"I was using uninitialized structures because they were automatic variables"* - "Automatic" relates to the object's lifetime. It is not the reason, or in any way related to the object being uninitialized. You can have uninitialized variables, automatic or otherwise. And you can (and should) have initialized variables, automatic or otherwise. Your compiler warned you about this. Don't ignore those warnings.